# Insert text into Text file with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a cursor on a table and for each iteration on the records of this table I want to generate a text and insert it in a txt file. Any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: Honestly though, thats not a good way to solve that problem. Your should have an app or script that pulls the data from the database and then writes it to disk.

Comment: @DaleK I just want to know how to export the content of nvarchar(max) variable into a text file which is in specific address on my system

Comment: Just use `sqlcmd` batch command, pass your query, and output it to file. SQL itself is not meant for writing things to disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

You can replace it with your cursor

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
RECONFIGURE;


Declare @RepID int,@String varchar(max)
Declare @Cursor as Cursor;

Set @Cursor = Cursor For
SELECT RepID,RepText FROM Reps   --<< Your QUERY goes here  

Open @Cursor;
Fetch Next From @Cursor into @RepID, @String;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    Declare @Destination varchar(150) 
    Set @Destination = @InputFolder + cast(@RepID as varchar(25)) +'.txt'
    Exec [dbo].[prc-Write-To-File] @String,@Destination 
    Fetch Next From @Cursor Into @RepID, @String;
End

Close @Cursor;
Deallocate @Cursor;
```

and this one too

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[prc-Write-To-File] (@text as Varchar(Max), 
@Filename Varchar(200)) AS
Begin
    Declare @Object int,@rc int,@FileID Int

    EXEC @rc = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @Object OUT
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @Object , 'OpenTextFile' , @FileID OUT , @Filename , 2 , 1
    Set @text = Replace(Replace(Replace(@text,'&','&'),'<' ,'<'),'>','>')
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @FileID , 'WriteLine' , Null , @text
    Exec @rc = MIMIC.dbo.sp_OADestroy @FileID
    Declare @Append bit
    Select @Append = 0
    If @rc <> 0
    Begin
        Exec @rc = MIMIC.dbo.sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SaveFile',null,@text ,@Filename,@Append
    End
    Exec @rc = MIMIC.dbo.sp_OADestroy @Object
End
```